# Is there any way to stop AWS Rekognition operation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

Is there any way to stop/cancel any Rekognition operation which was started earlier through its jobId or similar thing?

To elaborate it, lets assume that I have started a label detection operation using startLabelDetection method through which I get a jobId. I want to have an option to cancel/stop it ( also it would be great to have pause option ;) while the process is in progress.

I went through the documentation but did't find any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only stop AWS Rekognition operations when analyzing a stream (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_StopStreamProcessor.html). For all other operations you are billed a fixed amount per min of video, or per request, and you cannot stop the operation once it has been requested.